# How to disable the kendo Datetime picker in Kendo Grid by using jquery?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

```
$("#ElementId").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

The Above code only works for the Date pickers which are declared in Html page.

But I want to Disable the kendo Date picker in the kendo Grid Header Filter area.

Comment: if you don't want filtering on the column in your grid why not just turn filtering off and then the date picker will not be rendered. (Assuming this is what you want to actually have happen)

Comment: Dear David !!   Actually I want the filtering on the column in my grid, the problem was it is allowing invalid userinput. So i want to disabeling the invalid user input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of achieving what you want.

[Disabled text input on grid filter](http://dojo.telerik.com/UDOza)

I have modified the date cell to have the following:

```
{
     field: "OrderDate",
     title: "Order Date",
     format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
     filterable: {
         cell: {
             template: function (element) {



                 element.element.kendoDatePicker({

                 });

                 element.element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

             }
         }

     }
 }
```

You will notice that I have added a template to the cell which will override the default date picker and add my own date picker to the filter row.

**Note if you want to do this via the menu you just need to do this at the first element item e.g. element.kendoDatePicker({})**

Hope this is what you are after.

For more info on this take a look at this link: 
[kendo grid filter api](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.cell.template)